# Android activity force portrait in restricted hardwares

Tags: android, screen-orientation

I am developing an app especially for plug PC. Hardware of certain plug PC (ex: MK 809IV, 808II, etc) do not permit portrait mode of activity. Suggested method in some forums ask to inform using custom-ROM to achieve the same.

Is there a way through which I can programmatically mime portrait representation without using `android:screenOrientation="portrait"` or                 `activity.setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT)` ?

Comment: If methods you described fail, then it is really impossible and you can only make custom ROM.

Comment: you want to keep the app in portrait mode or in landscape mode?

Answer (score 0):

You either need to create a custom rom or you need to find a plug that will support the new Android N version. Then you can use the new split screen mode (multi-window). I am not sure if that will be in the Compat library or not (i doubt it). But then you can have your activity in portrait with another activity. This might be difficult to accomplish.